# I'm building an e-com project, and am stuck and unable route the react compo to the right one. am using this api https://fakestoreapi.com/products

Tags: reactjs, api, react-redux, routes

The problem am facing is, after displaying the categories in UI, I want to route them to a specific category and I want to store it in the redux too.
I did store the categories data in redux, but am unable to route them to the specific category page.
here my repo link https://github.com/PG0209/project-e-commers

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {selctedCategory} from '../Redux/Actions/productActions';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const SpecificCategory = () => {
    const categories = useSelector((state) => state.categories);
    // const product = useSelector((state) => state.product);
    const {productCategory} = useParams();
    console.log(productCategory);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    const fetchSpecificCategory = async () =>{
        const response = await axios
        .get(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/category/${productCategory}`)
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log("error", error);
        })
        dispatch(selctedCategory(response.data));
    }
    useEffect(() => {
          fetchSpecificCategory();
      }, []);
    
    return (
        <div className='cat'>
            <h1>want to display selected category here</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SpecificCategory;          

import React from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import {productCategories} from "../Redux/Actions/productActions";
import Category from './CategoryComponent';

const CategoryListing = () => {
  const categories = useSelector((state) => state);
  const dispatch = useDispatch( );

  const fetchCat = async () =>{
    const response = await axios
  .get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products/categories")
  .catch((error) =>{
    console.log("error", error);
  })
  dispatch(productCategories(response.data));
  }
  useEffect(() => {
     fetchCat();
  }, []);
  console.log("categories", categories);
    return (
        <>
          <Category/>
        </>
    )
}

export default CategoryListing
```